# Use of 'continue' with 'if'

Tags: grammar

I need to understand the correct use of 'continue' in the following.

> She would lose her job if she **continue** to behave like that.

Or

> She would lose her job if she **continues** to behave like that.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to ELU!

Neither sentence is correct, I'm afraid.

These are both correct:

> Past tense: *She would lose her job if she continued to behave like
>   that.*
>
> Present tense: *She will lose her job if she continues to behave like
>   that.*

Maybe these examples will make it clearer:

> I told her she would lose her job if she continued to . . .
>
> I told her, "You will lose your job if you continue to . . ."
>
> I am watching her. She will lose her job if she continues to . . .
>
> I watched her. She would lose her job if she continued to . . .

Comment: I'd love to know why this was voted down.